# Getting an error with this lambda function that is triggered by the createbucket event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I set up a Cloudwatch Event `CreateBucket` that triggers this automatic policy generating script:

```
import json

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get bucket name from the S3 event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']


    # Create a bucket policy
    bucket_policy =json.dumps({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedAtRest",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
         
                        "aws:kms"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedInTransit",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                    }
            }
        } ] })


    # Set the new policy
    s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy)
```

This lambda function should run and place this policy in the created bucket. However, it isnt running properly and testing through lambda interface give me this error:

```
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      9,
      "lambda_handler",
      "bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "errorMessage": "'Records'"
}
```

I need that policy to be attached to a new bucket everytime, no matter the name, but cant seem to figure out why it isnt working

EDIT::

````
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 10, in lambda_handler
    bucket_name = event['details']['requestParameters']['bucketName']
KeyError: 'details'```

Is the new error i get.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you’re using is not correct for the event, in fact AWS have [examples of events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#events-for-services-not-listed) in their documentation.

The real event looks like the below json

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "36eb8523-97d0-4518-b33d-ee3579ff19f0",
    "detail-type": "AWS API Call via CloudTrail",
    "source": "aws.s3",
    "account": "123456789012",
    "time": "2016-02-20T01:09:13Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "eventVersion": "1.03",
        "userIdentity": {
            "type": "Root",
            "principalId": "123456789012",
            "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root",
            "accountId": "123456789012",
            "sessionContext": {
                "attributes": {
                    "mfaAuthenticated": "false",
                    "creationDate": "2016-02-20T01:05:59Z"
                }
            }
        },
        "eventTime": "2016-02-20T01:09:13Z",
        "eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
        "eventName": "CreateBucket",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "sourceIPAddress": "100.100.100.100",
        "userAgent": "[S3Console/0.4]",
        "requestParameters": {
            "bucketName": "bucket-test-iad"
        },
        "responseElements": null,
        "requestID": "9D767BCC3B4E7487",
        "eventID": "24ba271e-d595-4e66-a7fd-9c16cbf8abae",
        "eventType": "AwsApiCall"
    }
}
```

To resolve the error your Lambda needs to use this structure for accessing the bucket name property.

To do this update your code to assign the
bucket_name variable like the below.

```
bucket_name = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']
```

The above event should be used as the event to test.

The working function is below

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get bucket name from the S3 event
    print(event)

    bucket_name = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']

    # Create a bucket policy
    bucket_policy =json.dumps({
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedAtRest",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "StringNotEquals": {
                        "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                            "AES256",
                            "aws:kms"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedInTransit",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:*",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "Bool": {
                        "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                        }
                }
            } ] })


    # Set the new policy
    s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy)
```

Comment: Will i need to edit my entire bucket policy code to match that structure?

Comment: No, just the bucket name variable at the top needs to reference the structure of the event :)

Comment: The policy is fine, it’s the event passed into the Lambda that is not the format you referred to on the bucket_name variable

Comment: I put the new error im getting. It seems like this event thing doesnt take the parameters

Comment: Sorry I mistyped should be detail not details

Comment: Im sorry but the error message now just says that ```detail``` is now the problem. Even tried seeing if it functions with a new bucket but as of now it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Hmm, try doing a print of the event first to view in CloudWatch logs for you Lambda

Comment: where will I be able to print the event? doing so in the lambda interface and testing only gives me the errors and not what runs. Sorry again I am new to this

Comment: If you put a print before assigning bucket_name variable, then once the Lambda is invoked check the CloudWatch logs. :)

Comment: ```{u'key3': u'value3', u'key2': u'value2', u'key1': u'value1', u'key4': u'Records'}
``` this is what appears on the log. Is this correct?

Comment: This looks like JSON for an event although I don't recognise the keys

Comment: seems to be working. it seems I just havent waited for the policy to load. Thank you so much for  the patience on this week long project :)

Comment: That’s no problem I am glad I could help, have a great rest of the week :)